# machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' while using libprotobuf in windows qt creator

Tags: c++, windows, qt, protocol-buffers

I installed protocol buffers version 3.1.0 on windows by downloading **protobuf-cpp-3.1.0.zip** from the [releases](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases) page. Then compiled and installed it using Developer Tools for Visual Studio. I copied **libprotobuf.lib** to the appropriate libraries' directory. After adding the library from **add library** option and choosing external library, when I tried to run qmake and build, it showed this error:

```
LNK1112 module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014227/lnk1112-module-machine-type-x86-conflicts-with-target-machine-type-x64) and it tells to either change the module object, which in this case is the protobuf library or change the linker target. I tried fiddling around with the qt creator tools but couldn't figure out how to change the target to 32-bit.

Is there no way I can get a 64-bit version of protobuf library for windows?

Comment: Compile and link against a 64-bit build of the library.

Comment: @IInspectable I couldn't find the 64-bit build. Could you tell me how to build the 64-bit version of the library using source?

Comment: [There are instructions on how to build on Windows](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/src#c-installation---windows).

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/14753/solved-how-to-build-64-bit-application